# Symfony Doctrine return empty values

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I use Symfony doctrine to set and get data from my MySQL database. I can push new data without any problem but when I try to get them with a findAll for exemple, I get an array with the good length but nothing in.

Here's my controller:

```
namespace KGN\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KGN\CoreBundle\Entity\Appointment;
use KGN\CoreBundle\Entity\Testy;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('KGNCoreBundle:Admin:index.html.twig');
    }


    public function aptAction()
    {

        $rep = $this->getDoctrine()
                                ->getRepository('KGNCoreBundle:Testy');

        $testy = $rep->findAll();


        // return new Response('This is for show : '. count($testy) );
        return new JsonResponse($testy);

    }

    public function createAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $testy = new Testy();

        $testy->setTitre('Magnifique');
        $testy->setName('Helicoptere');

        $em->persist($testy);

        $em->flush();

        return new Response('This is for create');

    }

}
```

and what I get on my view page

```
[{},{}]
```

And it's true that there is 2 elements in my SQL table.

( I have create my entity with php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity without edition stuff in the "Testy" class or rep )

Entity/Testy

```
namespace KGN\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Testy
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="testy")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KGN\CoreBundle\Repository\TestyRepository")
 */
class Testy
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return Testy
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Testy
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

associed rep

```
namespace KGN\CoreBundle\Repository;

/**
 * TestyRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class TestyRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
}
```

Comment: Could we see the mapping?

Comment: sure, i've edited the post

Comment: I thing you have to iterate the array. Try and tell..Regards

Comment: Already tryed, but that gave me an error when I try to get test.title for exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi The Function **findAll** Return the correct answer but its return as array of **Objects**
And **JsonResponse** can't desplay Object. 
to fixe that you have to create a custom function in your repository that return An array exemple

```
public function getAll() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');     


    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: Will try this in the worst case. But I don't realy need the JsonResponse, it's just to try. But still have error when I try to passe this object into a twig for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$records = $em->getRepository("KGNCoreBundle:Testy")->findAll();
```

Hope its help you

Comment: explain, it may be helpful to me if you explain